# Get wp_logout_url function to work on external (non-Wordpress) page

Tags: logout

I have blog and forum, and I need to put wordpress external logout link. What files do I need to add to make wp_logout_url(); work?

Thank you.

Comment: wp_logout_url uses functions such as apply_filter, wp_nonce_url, add_query arg. It is found in general-template.php. God knows what other Wordpress functions are being used in that file? Basically, you'd have to load Wordpress in its entirety. Which is why you would be much better off just finding out what the link is and then hardcoding it.

Comment: @Calle you can't hardcode the link since it needs [a nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I did not think to look that up! But if that's how it is then that's not very good. I still don't like the overhead of wp-blog-header.php just for one tiny link but in that case, that's probably the easiest way out.

Answer (score 1):

To allow WordPress functions to operate outside of the WordPress environment, you need to let your external pages know about and have access to the WordPress Core and API environment.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

The above link is one such reference which covers this very purpose.

Specifically,

> In order to transform regular PHP pages into ones that utilize WordPress, you need to add either of the following code snippets to the start of each page.

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

or

```
<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Getting your paths right is very important, without, you'll have no joy.

Refer to the [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) provided for even greater detail. Any problems thereafter please let us know along with what you have tried, code samples used, etc.

Good luck!

Comment: I would advise loading `wp-load.php`, as `wp-blog-header.php` will handle requests (which the OP probably won't want).