# Logout via Subdomain, non-wordpress page on a different server?

Tags: security, subdomains, logout

Similar to the question over at [Get wp_logout_url function to work on external (non-Wordpress) page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72547/get-wp-logout-url-function-to-work-on-external-non-wordpress-page)

The problem I am facing is the fact the subdomain is on a different server so I am unable to include/require the `wp-blog-header.php` file.

Is there a way that I can whitelist domains that can allow instant logouts, like you can for the [redirect whitelist](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/allowed_redirect_hosts).

If not, how can I allow subdomains (it has remote sql access) to create a valid logout link that bypasses the "Are you sure you want to logout" notice.

## Re: @SatbirKira

Does this like a logical work around to make sure the logout is "valid" to a certain degree:

- Set the logout URL every 24 hours to have a query string with a random string appended to it for example: `http://website.com/custom_logout.php?confirm=sj239ks`, followed by `http://website.com/custom_logout.php?confirm=32k9la3`

Each time it changes it would edit a specific file (custom_logout.php on the other server OR a txt/ini file on its own server OR other server) and create an array/list of strings

```
$confirmkeys = array("sj239ks", "32k9la3");
```

or

```
[confirmkeys]
confirm[] = sj239ks
confirm[] = 32k9la3
```

It would only ever have 2 confirm keys in the file, one for 24 hours ago (just incase someone has the page still open) and one for the current 24 hours)

**I guess the same thing could be done individually instead of globally but is there much need for that?**

- Edit `custom_logout.php` to add a check to see if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is coming from the same domain (all subdomains). If it is then set `matching_referer` to true. If not set the variable to false.
- Edit `custom_logout.php` to add a check to see if the query string matches against one stored inside a specific file. (easiest to do with a txt/ini file on the secondary server?) If it matches then set `matching_confirm` to true. If not set the variable to false.
- Edit `custom_logout.php` and make it so as long if one (any) of the checks are true for it to logout cleanly, if they are both false logout with the warning by sending them to the `/wp-login.php?action=logout` page?

Comment: It might work when you change WordPress' cookie domains to account for the sub domain, so that you can delete the WordPress cookie on the sub domain's server. If you're adventurous, you can also try deleting the session from the WordPress database but I wouldn't really recommend that when you don't have access to the WordPress code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file called custom_logout.php and place it in the root wordpress directory. This contains

```
<?php 
     require_once("wp-load.php"); //load wordpress
     wp_logout(); //logout
     exit(); //end page
?>
```

Then in your subdomain site open the url with an anchor tag

```
<a href="http://youwebsite.com/custom_logout.php">Logout</a>
```

You can't create a whitelist easily because it would involve checking where the user is coming from using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] which is unreliable(usually null). There is no simple solution for this unfortunately.

**Reply To Your Edit**

You are completely free to implement the temporary key approach if that is a responsible compromise. However, instead of two random keys you can send a md5 hash of the current day. Use an identical secret salt on both servers. Now you can simply recompute yesterday's hash and the current day's in custom_logout.php and compare it to the get variable that is incoming. It eliminates the need for a txt/ini file.

Comment: This misses the point that the sub domain is on a different server and including `wp-load.php` (usually not a good idea  anyways) is not possible.

Comment: @swissspidy You and OP was correct in saying it is not possible to require across servers. However the solution I suggested does not do this.

Comment: So where do you magically get `wp-load.php`from when it's not on the same server?

Comment: The file custom_logout.php is placed on the main server with the wordpress session we wish to end. It is opened via an anchor tag from the different server.

Comment: @SatbirKira I've edited my post, I'd like to see your thoughts on it and maybe it gives you an idea on other ways of getting a reliable check to see if the logout is more `legitimate`.

Comment: @Ryflex this answer and your ideas in the updated question doesn't solve the security issue (CSRF) nonce was introduced to solve. I'll explain why & perhaps even how to get around that.

Comment: @Ryflex I've updated my answer.

Comment: @SatbirKira even adding hash doesn't help much, i.e. cannot replace  nonce. Anyone can still get the logout url by fetching the webpage from the sub domain & then spoof HTTP_REFERER.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are the administrator of both sites...

Add admin ajax handler in your main wp site...

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_logout', 'my_logout_callback' );
function my_logout_callback() {
    wp_logout(); // Log out
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/successfully-logged-out');// Maybe redirect user somewhere?
    wp_die();
}
```

In your subdomain site link to main site's admin ajax handler...

```
<a href='//example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=logout'>Logout</a>
```